# At least a prime k-tuple

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $k \in\mathbb{N}, k \geq 2$, and $\mathbb{P}$ represent the set of prime numbers.

Consider the k-tuple $(0,h_1,h_2,\cdots,h_{k-1})$ with $0 < h_1 < \cdots < h_{k-1}$.

The well known k-tuple conjecture states:

> If the k-tuple $(0,h_1,h_2,\cdots,h_{k-1})$ **is admissible** then they are infinitly many k-tuples $(p,p+h_1,\cdots,p+h_{k-1})\in\mathbb{P}^{k}$

*(The k-tuple $(0,h_1,h_2,\cdots,h_{k-1})$ is admissible iff $\forall p \in \mathbb{P} \,\, ,p(p+h_1)\cdots(p+h_{k-1})$ haven't a **fix prime divisor**)*

I ask if we can prove:

> If the k-tuple $(0,h_1,h_2,\cdots,h_{k-1})$ **is admissible** then exists at least a k-tuple that $(p,p+h_1,\cdots,p+h_{k-1})\in\mathbb{P}^{k}$

Comment: No. Using larger tuples, you can prove if that for any tuple there is at least one k-tuple, then there are infinitely many.

Comment: @Wojow, you see the idea .. we move from k-tuple to (k+1)-tuple, (k+2)-tuple,. then the existence of at least prime k-tuple implies infinitly many k-tuple primes ..

Comment: What you ask is not even known for $k=2$. That is, we don't know whether every even integer is a difference of two primes.

Comment: @GH: what is the best $\delta>0$ so far so that the proportion of even integers that are the difference of two primes is at least $\delta$?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: I think the best known result is recorded in (1.2) of the following paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.8198v2

Comment: Ok, thank you much for your answer.